# What is the quickest way to Open Graph meta tag images in my Vue SPA?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, aws-amplify, vite, meta-tags

I have a VueJS 3 single page application using Vite, and deployed on AWS Amplify (frontend only). The application involves NFTs and it's important that links shared on socials (especially Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter) are rendering an image of the specific NFT when sharing a link to its view.  In a separate repository, and under a different domain, we have a simple Express API, that gets called in the VueJS application in a few places.

I have looked into options to solve this problem, and come up with a few options:

1. Full re-write in a SSR framework like Nuxt.js (the routing poses the biggest hurdle here)
2. Do pre-rendering before each deployment. I am not sure if this fits our use case. The URL for the NFT view is dynamic (`{baseURL}/nft/{UUID_OF_NFT}`) and NFTs can be created on the platform.
3. Write some logic in a Lambda Edge function that checks if the request is coming from a bot/crawler, if it is, make some calls to the DB, return some HTML with the proper meta tags. If not render the SPA.

I have not had any success with any of these options yet. I need help in determining if I missed any option that will get me there quicker, or which option here is considered the most viable and simple. The option involving the least effort will be preferred.

For option 1, I tried implementing the vite template for `vue-ssr`. I was never able to get it to run locally, as some of my dependencies are not compatible with SSR. There may be a way forward after determining which dependencies should be client only. I haven't given option 2 and honest try yet, as it seems like the least preferable to me.

For option 3, I tried to pull down my Amplify project through the CLI, but it failed because there is no backend environment associated with it. It was deployed as a front end only on Amplify. I believe a backend environment is needed to add the Lambda@Edge function.

Comment: The question looks too broad for SO at this moment, consider focusing on specific solutions. Since you're open to alternative approaches, they will be suggested if there are any. "For option 1, I tried implementing the vite template for vue-ssr" - ditching a potential solution half-way doesn't seem constructive

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I certainly didn’t ditch that option. I hit a roadblock in that vue-router itself was having issues with SSR. I understand that the question is vague, but still I think it provides value as there must be a multitude of people who face this issue with SPAs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.